# What is this PCB component from an older CRT display?

Tags: display, crt

I have an old CRT Display that used to dim out every morning and would require significant warmup before it reached normal brightness. A repair guy worked on it. He did some stuff and asked me to notify him if the problem reappears again. The Display is working for now.

After he left, I discovered that a PCB component left outside, which I suspect is a CRT Display component. I'm posting / linking a Photograph with my Question so anyone savvy with Display hardware can identify it and tell me if it's anything crucial or am I entirely mistaken.

A Photograph is provided below:

[image: The Component I cannot Identify]

Comment: Why don't you just ask the technician? He should know what parts he disassembled. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the 6 components on the top are buttons... don't you have 6 buttons on your CRT? if so, it looks like he replaced the buttons' PCB.

Comment: The buttons on the CRT is working just fine right now. So if it is what you say it is, it did not affect the button behavior at all.

Comment: Most likely he replaced some other PCB and the replacement came with a replacement button PCB. That may be your original one or the new one he didn't use.